# I get the error "index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]' " when implementing search in my app

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uisearchbar

Here's my code. While following multiple tutorials on how to implement search in Swift I've had no luck.

```
import UIKit

class DataTableExercisesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var exercises = ["Abs", "Arms", "Back", "Chest", "Legs", "Shoulders", "Triceps"]
var searchActive : Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}



// MARK: - Table view data source



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return exercises.count;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell;
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = exercises[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (exercises as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}




 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {




    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I've been having trouble implementing search from different tutorials and just doesn't seem to be working out too well. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` is always returning `exercises.count`. But when you are filtering, you are not using `exercises`, but a smaller array, `filteredTableData`. So, just as in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to change your answer if you are filtering.

Comment: So I need to change 'filteredTableData' to accept my exercises string? How can I do that?

Comment: "So I need to change 'filteredTableData' to accept my exercises string" I don't know what you're talking about, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is before access the array value just the check the total count should less the the index you want fetch from the array or use below way to iterate the array

EX :

```
let arrayOfInts: [Int] = [1, 2, 3];          
  for i in arrayOfInts {
      print(i);
  }
```

In your case you could change the code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     var rowCount = 0
    if(self.resultSearchController.active){
      rowCount = filteredTableData.count
    }
    else{
      rowCount = exercises.count
    }
    return rowCount;
}
```